# How to Pass property selection as parameter

Tags: arrays, csv, select, powershell-3.0

I have csv files with various columns/fields in.  I have a script that processes the csv files.
I want to pass into the script the properties I want to select from the csv file.

e.g. if the csv file looks like:

HotfIxId, Name, Date, IsInstalled

and I want to select just HotfixId and Date, I do:

```
Import-Csv path.csv | select -Property HotfixId,Date
```

this works.

However if I pass in "HotfixId,Date" as a parameter called $columnsParam

and then in the script do

```
Import-Csv path.csv | select -Property $columnsParam
```

this doesnt work, I just get an empty return with 1 column titled

HotfixId,Date

How do I pass in the properties to the script and or how do I use/dereference them in the select -property statement?

Many thanks

Comment: `$columnsParam` must be an array: `$columnsParam = "HotfixId","Date"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CB. said in the comments to your question, the property list must be an array:

```
$columnsParam = 'HotfixId', 'Date'
Import-Csv path.csv | select -Property $columnsParam
```

If you define `$columnsParam` as a single string, `Select-Object` will select the (non-existent) property `HotfixId,Date` instead of the two properties `HotfixId` and `Date`.

Comment: Thanks guys, $columns param is already defined as an array [string[]] $columnsParam.  do i need to pass the parameters to the script like "HotfixId","Date"   rather than "HotfixID,Date"  ?  I'll try it.  Thanks

Comment: @Keith yes. using `"HotfixID,Date"` is only one value of the array placed in $columns[0] position.